# Delphereum buy token direct bscscan

Tags: delphi, bscscan

i found the library
[delphereum](https://github.com/svanas/delphereum) and I'm trying to implement it, I'd like to swap directly in bscscan with [SwapExactETHForTokens](https://github.com/svanas/delphereum/blob/master/web3.eth.uniswap.v2.pas), but I didn't find documentation or examples, I'm doing the following, but I get error "Acess violation"

```
const
  URL = 'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org';
var
  pvk: TPrivatekey;
  valor, min : BigInteger;
  TokenAdd : TAddress;
  unxTimeMin : Int64;
  rt2 : TRouter02;
begin
  pvk := '6c87eae6cad6c9f160878f99660ee17fb6d48b867defa67cdf733a496d4ebfaf';
  valor := web3.eth.utils.toWei('0.0003', ether);
  min := web3.eth.utils.toWei('0', ether);
  unxTimeMin := 10;
  TokenAdd := '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c, 0x7AE5709c585cCFB3e61fF312EC632C21A5F03F70';

  rt2 := web3.eth.uniswap.v2.TRouter02.Create(TWeb3.Create(URL));
  rt2.SwapExactETHForTokens(pvk, valor, min, TokenAdd, unxTimeMin,
  procedure(rcpt : ITxReceipt; err : IError)
  begin
    TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
    begin
      if Assigned(err) then
        MessageDlg(err.Message, TMsgDlgType.mtError, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], 0)
      else
       mJson.Lines.Add(rcpt.txHash);
       ShowMessage('Hash: ' + rcpt.txHash);
    end);
  end);
end;
```

I'm confused about the parameters I have to pass, I would like to do the same as demonstrated in this [example in python](https://github.com/CodeWithJoe2020/pancakeswapBot/blob/main/cakebot.py)

Comment: You get the AV **where**? Also note that `ShowMessage` is not bound to your `else` route anymore and is always executed.

Comment: on thread return